# how to add a datetimepicker type column in DataGridView

Tags: sql-server-2008, nhibernate, c#-4.0

I have a table that has a column named "From" which has "Date" datatype.

I want to add a column in my DataGridView which can select a date like datetimepicker.

Can anyone suggest me how to add a datetimepicker type column in DataGridView

Answer (score 0):

You can use XAML to add the DatePicker object or the DateTimePicker (depending on what is available) into your DataGridView. Simply name it something like "dtp_whateverYouLike" and use it in your code.